# Scala and Java - Implicit Parameters and Inheritance

Tags: scala, implicit

The following code gives an error:

```
package test

trait Base {
  def method:String
}

trait Trait extends Base {
  def method()(implicit i:String):String = { "2" }
}

object Object extends Trait {

}
```

The error is **"object creation impossible, since method method in class Base of type => String is not defined"**

The above error is fixed by following code

```
package test

trait Base {
  def method:String
}

trait Trait extends Base {
  def method:String = method()("String") // Over loading
  def method()(implicit i:String):String = { "2" }
}

object Object extends Trait {

}
```

Now instead of Scala class, when I define a Java interface as follows:

```
// Java Code
package test;

public interface JBase {
  String method();
}

// Scala Code
package test

trait Trait extends JBase {
  def method:String = method()("10")
  def method()(implicit i:String):String = { "2" }
}

object Object extends Trait {

}
```

I get an error **"ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method method in trait Trait of type ()(implicit i: String)String and  method method in trait Trait of type ()String match argument types ()"**

What is the difference in both these scenarios that makes the compiler behave differently? How do I solve this issue?

Comment: A method with parentheses can't override a method without

Comment: Also, I would make it a general rule of thumb that ___if you resort to overloading in Scala then you are doing something wrong.___

Comment: What are the alternatives to overloading? The java interface here is not controlled by me i.e. it is part of a library. I thought use of an implicit is a cool way of maintaining library signatures for api calls while adding additional functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example that I think shows clearly what is going on:

```
object Test extends App {
    class A { def f(): String = "x" }
    class B extends A { override def f: String = "y" }
    class C { def f: String = "z" }

    println { (new A).f() } // OK
    println { (new B).f() } // OK
    println { (new C).f() } // FAILS
}
```

- `A`: Has parentheses, called with parentheses, everything good.
- `B`: Has *no* parentheses, but supertype *does* have parentheses, so still good. This corresponds to your case.
- `C`: Has no parentheses, called with parentheses, no good.

Basically, Java methods are always considered "with parentheses", so, `Trait`'s supertype has the parentheses, so using parentheses in `method()("string")` is insufficient to clarify which method you mean.

---

**edit**: Honestly I think you are better off renaming the method. Even in the case where there is no ambiguity, the behavior could be quite surprising:

```
trait Trait {
    def method: String = method()("x")
    def method()(implicit i: String): String = i
}

val t = new Trait { }
implicit val s = "y"

println { t.method }
> "x"

println { t.method() }
> "y"
```

Furthermore, the fact that the name is the same isn't buying you anything in terms of polymorphism: only the non-implicit method overrides `Base.method` -- it's just an aesthetic decision to make the names be the same.

Comment: So what would you suggest as a solution to this problem. I have a Java interface from a compiled Jar. I thought implicit parameters are a cool trick. I would like to maintain the signatures of the interface and still add one parameter which I want to set implicitly.

Comment: @0n4li See my edit. Maybe what you want to will depend on what `method()` does and why you are overriding `Base`, but as it is it seems too risky to me to leave the names the same.